# lidar is detecting pillars of robots as obstacles in local map.how to set minimum range of scan sensor or any other method to solve this problem

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have placed my rplidar a1 sensor in the middle of 4 pillar robot. now during navigation it detecting pillars as local obstacle.please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342169/lidar-is-detecting-pillars-of-robots-as-obstacles-in-local-map.how-to-set-minimum-range-of-scan-sensor-or-any-other-method-to-solve-this-problem/) by [vishrut](https://answers.ros.org/users/51111/vishrut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you talking about a local cost map?  If you are using the [obstacles layer](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles), there is a `footprint_clearing_enabled` parameter, which defaults to `true`.  Make sure it is not set accidentally set to `false`.  If it's still not clearing, ensure that your footprint is properly defined.  This is also important for avoiding obstacles in general.

That said, the [`laser_filters` package](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters#LaserScanRangeFilter) (as Procópio suggested) is probably also useful as it will remove the pillars from the data stream completely.  This will likely improve the quality of SLAM and other applications of your lidar data.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2020-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3